# Longest meditation period of historical Buddha

Tags: reference-request, meditation, the-buddha, buddha

Is there any record of the longest period the historical Buddha stayed in meditation?  I have heard rumors ranging from many days to many weeks.  Also when?  Prior to his first sermon or after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following suttas, it was recorded that the Buddha sat in unbroken meditation for seven days, before emerging. This occurred right after he became fully enlightened.

> I have heard that on one occasion, the Blessed One was staying at
> Uruvelā on the bank of the Nerañjarā River at the root of the Bodhi
> tree — the tree of awakening — newly awakened. And on that occasion he
> sat at the root of the Bodhi tree for **seven days in one session**,
> sensitive to the bliss of release. At the end of seven days, he
> emerged from that concentration.
> [Ud 1.4](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.1.04.than.html)

> Thus have I heard. At one time the Lord was staying at Uruvela, beside
> the river Nerañjara at the foot of the Bodhi Tree, having just
> realized full enlightenment. At that time the Lord sat cross-legged
> for **seven days** experiencing the bliss of liberation. Then, at the end
> of those seven days, the Lord emerged from that concentration and gave
> well-reasoned attention during the first watch of the night to
> dependent arising in forward order.
> [Ud 1.1](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.1.01.irel.html)

> I have heard that on one occasion, the Blessed One was staying at
> Uruvelā on the bank of the Nerañjarā River at the root of the Bodhi
> tree — the tree of awakening — newly awakened. And on that occasion he
> sat at the root of the Bodhi tree for **seven days in one session**,
> sensitive to the bliss of release. Then, with the passing of seven
> days, after emerging from that concentration, he surveyed the world
> with the eye of an Awakened One. As he did so, he saw living beings
> burning with the many fevers and aflame with the many fires born of
> passion, aversion, & delusion.
> [Ud 3.10](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.3.10.than.html)

> Thus have I heard. At one time the Lord was staying at Uruvela beside
> the river Nerañjara at the foot of the Mucalinda Tree, having just
> realized full enlightenment.
>
> At that time the Lord sat cross-legged for **seven days** experiencing the
> bliss of liberation. Now it happened that there occurred, out of
> season, a great rainstorm and for seven days there were rain clouds,
> cold winds, and unsettled weather. Then Mucalinda the naga-king left
> his dwelling place and having encircled the Lord's body seven times
> with his coils, he stood with his great hood spread over the Lord's
> head (thinking) to protect the Lord from cold and heat, from gadflies,
> mosquitoes, wind, sun, and the touch of creeping things.
>
> At the end of those seven days the Lord emerged from that
> concentration. Then Mucalinda the naga-king, seeing that the sky had
> cleared and the rain clouds had gone, removed his coils from the
> Lord's body. Changing his own appearance and assuming the appearance
> of a youth, he stood in front of the Lord with his hands folded
> together venerating him.
> [Ud 2.1](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.2.01.irel.html)